# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string site:community.oracle.com

Tags: java, oracle11g, prepared-statement

Could you please help what wrong with this query when calling from Java. When I run the same query in PL/SQL developer it runs perfectly but not when i call from java,.

CRE_DTTM  is in DATE datatype

```
String query4="SELECT NVL(SUM(cur_amt),0) FIRST_PAY" +
                        "   FROM ci_ft ft " +
                        "WHERE sa_id IN "+
 " (SELECT sA_id FROM ci_Sa WHERE acct_id='"+acctid.getIdValue()+"'  )" +
 "AND TRUNC(crE_dttm)>=  (SELECT MAX(crE_Dttm)  FROM ci_bill" +
 "  WHERE accT_id='"+acctid.getIdValue()+"'  AND crE_dttm<=    (SELECT add_months(To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), -1)    FROM dual )  )" +
 "AND fT_type_flg IN ('PS','PX')AND ft.cRE_dttm <= (" +
 "  CASE" +
 "    WHEN ( to_Date(" +
 "      (SELECT MAX(crE_Dttm)" +
 "      FROM ci_bill" +
 "      WHERE accT_id    ='"+acctid.getIdValue()+"'" +
 "      AND crE_dttm     < To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD')" +
 "      ) , 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_Date (" +
 "      (SELECT MAX(crE_Dttm)" +
 "      FROM ci_bill" +
 "      WHERE accT_id='"+acctid.getIdValue()+"'" +
 "      AND crE_dttm<=" +
 "        (SELECT add_months(To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), -1) FROM dual" +
 "        )      ) ,'YYYY-MM-DD'))" +
 "    THEN To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD')" +
 "    ELSE" +
 "    ( SELECT MAX(crE_Dttm)" +
 "      FROM ci_bill" +
 "      WHERE accT_id='"+acctid.getIdValue()+"'" +
 "      AND crE_dttm < To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD')) " +
 "  END)";


                com.splwg.base.api.sql.PreparedStatement ps4 = createPreparedStatement(query4);
                logger.info(ps4);
                ps4.execute();

                if(!ps4.list().isEmpty())
                {
                    first_pay=new BigDecimal(ps4.list().get(0).get("FIRST_PAY").toString());
                    logger.info("first_pay=="+first_pay);
                }
            }
```

The error is:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string site:community.oracle.com
```

Please note the PreparedStatement is from `com.splwg.base.api.sql.PreparedStatement`

Comment: have you tried printing out the string and plugging that into sql developer?  This looks like a mess, probably something better suited to a stored proc.

Comment: Problem is probably with different NLS_DATE_FORMAT value in PL/SQL developer and JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing different date formats in your where clause. Please try matching the date format of crE_dttm with To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD')

e.g. to_date(crE_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD') < To_Date('2016-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD')

Thanks
Sabiha